# How to add multiple Root CA in rabbitMQ windows?

Tags: windows, rabbitmq

```
{ssl_options, [{cacertfile,"c:/rootCA.pem"},
                   {certfile,"c:/Server.pem"},
                   {keyfile,"c:/Server.key"},
                   {verify,verify_peer},
                   {fail_if_no_peer_cert, true}]},
```

Above is the piece of config file that I am using. It works fine. The problem is I need to add multiple RootCA as the client uses different CA than Server and I need to trust both of them. I did some Googling and found {cacerts} tag which doesn't seem to work. Please help me on how to add multiple CA in RabbitMQ config in windows.

Comment: I think it's better to ask these kind of questions on our mailing list https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/rabbitmq-users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open .pem files of CA in some text editor and copy the contents. Append the copied contents to CA file used by rabbitmq